# Render date with url instead of calendar

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a notebook where people can leave a note, they can set the note for later and find a note a request date.

It is render as a calendar, I would like to have a link, for example, for the last 3 days and the next 3 days.

I don’t where to begin.

My views.py

```
start_date = request.GET.get('start_date')
        end_date = request.GET.get('end_date')

        set_start_date = None
        set_end_date = None

        if start_date and end_date:
            try:
                datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
                datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")

                set_start_date = start_date
                set_end_date = end_date
            except:
                messages.error(request, _(f"The form is invalid"))
                return redirect('workspace-detail', token=token)
```

My models.py

```
class Notebook(models.Model):
workspace = models.ForeignKey(Workspace, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='notes')
author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='author')
message = models.CharField(max_length=3000, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Publier une note")
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a url like `mywebsite.com/calendar?days=-3` (note the negative sign for minus 3 days) or `mywebsite.com/calendar?days=3`

Then this function would do the trick (adapting it to your current structure, of course)

```
from datetime import datetime  
from datetime import timedelta  

def getNewDate(date, days):
    if days > 0:
        # add days
        return date + timedelta(days=days)
    else:
        # subtract days
        return date - timedelta(days=days*-1)

# tests

# 3 days in the past, starting from today
print getNewDate(datetime.now(), -3)

# 3 days in the future, starting from today
print getNewDate(datetime.now(), 3)
```

Results:

```
2019-12-07 11:24:30.456000  
2019-12-13 11:24:30.456000
```

Comment: It is built with django, see the tag i have added.
Yes but I don't want an end date, that was my question.
See my code, I have already built something similar

Comment: So something like `mywebsite.com/calendar?days=-3` (note the negative sign for minus 3 days) or `mywebsite.com/calendar?days=3` ?

Comment: Yes that something like this that I want